# eclipse, java & running a project from terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, classpath

I'm used to writing java in eclipse and using it to import JARs, set up workspace, etc. however, when I want to deploy a project to my server and call it from a bash script like `java Main arg1 arg2` something isn't write I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

is my classpath set wrong? what is eclipse doing behind the scenes? when I do

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

I always get a blank line. The below (executed from bin folder) doesn't work either:

```
java -cp "~/Code/Java/SQL/MySQLAccess/bin;/usr/bin/java;/Users/Me/Code/Java/SQL/MySQLTest/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar" Main arg1 arg2 ... arg7
```

this gives me a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main` error

Comment: There is no classpath (`-cp`) in your command line

Comment: What package is Main in?

Comment: @Dev, I have no package description at the top of my Main.java code. my project is called MySQLAccess if that helps

Comment: Note that the *path separator* on Unix is `:` where on Windows it is `;`. Your paths are unix-like, but you use separators for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to be moving this around and deploying to potentially different servers, look into exporting your project as a jar.  You can include the sql jars inside your jar and your invocation from the script will look like

```
java -jar Main.jar
```

From Eclipse, you can go to File->Export, then pick 'jar' from the menu and follow the steps.

Your [manifest](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html) will be something like

```
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

your class path is not set correct, you can use command java -classpath path_for_java javafile argumnets

As far as eclipse is concerned you can go to project->properties->java build path->libraries and you will get to know from where eclipse is referring to java libraries.